# CSS hover animations playing on page load

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I've been playing around with animations on hover with pure CSS, applying the animation to element:hover and then the same animation to the regular element in reverse so that when the mouse is moved away the element returns to it's original state, this works fine however any animation that is fired when a user moves their mouse away from an element also runs on page load. I understand why this happens, but I would like to know if there's a way to stop it at all? Preferably not using JS but I don't see how that would be possible really

Current code being used, simple animations on hover:

```
.image{
  animation: hoverout 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.image:hover{
  animation: hover 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes hover{
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100%{
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

@keyframes hoverout{
  0%{
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  100%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: We will need to see your code. Can you edit your post to show what you have?

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried ?

Comment: You could use transitions instead.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `animation` and `keyframes` on such a simple hover. Use `transition` instead. A `transition` simply transitions between 2 points, in this case between the hover state and the non-hover state.

It would look something like this:

```
.image {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.image:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

In this case I set the `opacity` to transition on hover. You can add more values to this with commas such as `transition: opacity 300ms, color 300ms` or simplify it by transitioning everything `transition: all 300ms`, although that will take more performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a problem.

1) you can use `visibility` to solve it. Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.image')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
}, 1000)

element {
    visibility: hidden;
}

element:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('.image')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
   }, 1000)
});
```

```css
.image-parent {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.image-parent .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
    animation: hoverout 1s ease-in-out;
}

.image-parent:hover .image {
    visibility: visible;
    animation: hover 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes hover {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}

@keyframes hoverout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-parent">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) may help u.

2) If you are using `animation` and `keyframe`, u can replace them by `transition` and `opacity`. Eg:

```
element {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 1s, transform 0.5s;
}

element:hover {
    opacity:1;
    transform : rotateX(90deg);
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) may help u.

```css
.image-parent {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.image:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-parent">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```